# Нужна ли в данном предложении запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

недавно у блогера увидела такое предложение: **"На волне сегодняшних новостей, напоминаю..."** В связи с этим возник вопрос: нужна ли здесь запятая? Если нужна, то при каком условии?

Answer (score 3):

Очень сильно не хватает продолжения предложения. Запятая здесь, по-видимому, не будет обязательной, но она может использоваться, чтобы подчеркнуть причинное значение обстоятельственного оборота. Похожая конструкция встречается [в вопросе № 255226](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=255226) на gramota.ru.

Comment: Каким образом этот оборот может иметь значение причины? Это всего лишь указание на источник  информации.

Comment: @Sharon вторая часть предложения начинается с «напоминаю», поэтому не похожа на информацию из *сегодняшних* новостей

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от контекста.

Что обозначает обстоятельственный оборот? Если это просто **указание на источник информации**, то запятая не нужна.

**Обособляем** (и тем самым подчеркиваем) оборот в том случае, если речь идет **о сравнении**: это говорили **вчера**, а это говорится уже **сегодня**.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 27.05.2020

Это дополнение для тех читателей, кому **не нравится выражение** "указание на источник информации", но **нравится значение причины**, которую я здесь никак не могу разглядеть (имеются ввиду причинно-следственные отношения между оборотом и остальной частью предложения).

1) Обычно "указание на источник информации" относится к тематике вводных слов, но я **ни в коем случае не отношу оборот к вводным словам.** Я его всего лишь **ПОДЧЕРКИВАЮ**.

2) Мне сложно додумать текст, но обособление связано с постановкой логического ударения следующим образом: **На волне сегОдняшних новостей, напоминаю..."**  При отсутствии ударения оборот не обособлялся бы.

3) **Вообще говоря,**  правомерность обособления падежных обстоятельственных оборотов определяется так. **Во-первых**, у автора должен быть **повод** для  логического выделения  оборота. **Во-вторых,** **структура** предложения должна позволять ему это сделать.

4) Поэтому уже неоднократно приходится напоминать о том, что **без контекста** решать задачи по пунктуации или сложно, или невозможно вообще.